# Raspberry PI 3 Spark Cluster: WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: scala, hadoop, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing

I successfully installed Hadoop on the 3 nodes cluster and I am able to run a map-reduce program across the cluster. I want to compare the performance of map reduce with Spark, so I installed Spark. 
I want to make a comparison between a wordcount program running on map reduce vs running on Spark.

I followed this tutorial: 
http://bailiwick.io/2015/07/07/create-your-own-apache-spark-cluster-using-raspberry-pi-2/

I configured one of the Raspberry Pi node as a Master and the other two as slaves.

spark-env.sh (The same on all nodes)
[image]

slaves (The same on all nodes)
[image]

This is the code that I am running on Scala:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-shell --master spark://node1:7077

val changeFile = sc.textFile("/opt/spark/mediumfile.txt")
val changeFileLower = changeFile.map(_.toLowerCase)
val changeFlatMap = changeFileLower.flatMap("[a-z]+".r findAllIn _)
val changeMR = changeFlatMap.map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
changeMR.take(10)
```

When the console executes the last line of the code, it shows this error: 
WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster  UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I've tried to increase the worker memory in the spark-env.sh file or include the number of cores, but nothing worked.

Comment: Increase the memory by how much? Raspberry pi doesn't have that much memory available to start with, and Spark likes as much memory as it can take

Comment: Every Raspberry PI has 1 GB memory which is enough for this job.  I've tried to run the Scala shell without using ` --master spark://node1:7077` and the program finished successfully but on a single node (The master node). So I don't think it's a resources problem, but a configuration problem may be.